# Can I bundle a bundle of all javascript .js files?

Tags: javascript, jsp, jawr

On jsp page am including js bundles.  And I need all of these bundles (.js files). Can I create a bundle of bundles in Jawr so that i can add single line?  or should I create new bundle hand-picking all the .js files and group them in a new bundle?

bundle 1:-

```
jawr.js.bundle.global.id=/js/bundle/global.js
jawr.js.bundle.global.mappings=\
/js/underscore.js,\
/js/home.js,\
/js/home/util.js,\
/js/home/fb.js
```

bundle 2:-

```
jawr.js.bundle.reqPath.id=/js/bundle/reqPath.js
jawr.js.bundle.reqPath.mappings=\
/js/duplicateCheck.js,\
/js/jQuery/jquery.dimensions.pack.js
```

so on.. having 15 bundles.  I need 8 of these bundles (about 22 js files). Just curious if I can write one bundle of bundles and write one single line include in jsp pages.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried creating all-inclusive bundles (assuming all your js sits on a parent folder), eg:

```
jawr.js.bundle.everything.id=/bundles/everything.js
jawr.js.bundle.everything.mappings=/js/**
```